# Возможно ли хранить параметры подключения в файле .env в одном ключе?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Возможно ли хранить параметры подключения в файле .env в одном ключе, если в файле .js они записаны следующим образом:

```
const CONNECTION_PARAMS = {
    port: 102,
    host: '192.168.0.1',
    rack: 0,
    slot: 1,
    debug: false};
```

Comment: Например все это можно сохранить в строке формата `JSON`...

Comment: Создал файл params.json. Вставил предложенную запись. Все подчеркнуто красным, за исключением ```{"port": 102, "host": "192.168.0.1", "rack": 0, "slot": 1, "debug": false}```

Comment: Выделенное тобой и есть JSON-строка. Только такое и должно быть в json-файле. Но вопрос ты задавал не такой.... ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Возможно ли хранить параметры подключения в файле .env в одном ключе

Например в строке формата `JSON`...

```
const CONNECTION_PARAMS = `{"port": 102, "host": "192.168.0.1", "rack": 0, "slot": 1, "debug": false}`
```

> в файле .js они записаны следующим образом

Посмотри внимательно как там записано. Поскольку твой пример синтаксически неверен.